# Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined (client side js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, plugins, frontend, youtube-api

Im trying to create a youtube plugin (source code: https://github.com/abhishek-jha-24/EXTENSION)
The main javascript code is in content_scripts.js file and from that file i want to access a script1.py file which will give me some data and to access that .py file i've used this tutorial https://medium.com/swlh/run-python-script-from-node-js-and-send-data-to-browser-15677fcf199f

However when i add my extension to chrome it gives me this err:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

and now i got to know that we cannot use require in client side JavaScript, but without require how would i access the spawn module from NodeJS which is giving me access to my python file.

Comment: `require` does not exists on the client side. Its exists only in node.js. Neither can you execute python scripts in the clients browser...

Comment: @marc so marc can you please suggest me any other way by which i can access data from a python file, like i can create an api and host my python file and than access it but is there any easier method?

Comment: no way. The only possible solution is to host the python code on your own server, and expose it over a http api which you call from your browser extension. But im not sure if HTTP requests are allowed for extensions.

Comment: Ohh will look into it, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

use `import {spawn} from "child_process"`

Comment: using import im getting this err Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your code it seems that you are trying to run that code in a browser. It is not possible because you are trying to access apis specific to nodejs in browser.

Comment: So do you know any other method using which I can access data from py file from inside a js file.